# (epbf) Unable to use string.h apis on string that probe read from kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, ebpf, bpf

When I tried to do some string operations (strlen, strcpy and strtok) today, I found it is unable to use those string.h apis on string probe read from kernel.
It will raise **unknown opcode** error on python bcc/bpf and raise **libbpf: failed to find BTF for extern 'strlen'** on libbpf.

A pseudo code I tried as follows:

```c
u64 ptr = PT_REGS_PARMX(regs);
char str1[10] = {};
char str2[10] = "test";
bpf_probe_read_kernel(str1, sizeof(str1), (const void *) ptr);
u64 len = strlen(str1);    // error will raise here
len = strlen(str2);        // but this is ok if string not read from kernel
```

Although strlen I could implement in:

```c
u64 len = 0;
for(len; len < sizeof(str1); len++){
    if (str1[len] == '\0') break;
}
```

I still wonder that why it is unable to use string.h apis
and how could make it able to use.

Comment: i have the same question, how to find string length in eBPF?

Comment: Implementing `strlen()` yourself is the way to go unfortunately. I've answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't call arbitrary kernel functions from BPF bytecode.**

The reason it works for str2 is because it's a constant and the compiler therefore optimizes it to 4 without needing to call `strlen`.

If you need to compute the length of a string, you need to implement `strlen()` yourself or to copy one of the kernel's implementations. Note that in general, it is not recommended to perform computation on strings in BPF; that's a job better left to the userspace counterpart.

Comment: You explained clearly, thank you.